# Sockets y Opencv webcam streaming no responde c++

Tags: c++, socket, opencv, networking

He estado programando un programa de streaming de webcam en directo, en el que un programa cliente, envía un video al servidor. Hice el networking y funcionaba bien. Estuve viendo muchos videos e informándome acerca de como enviar streams de la webcam directamente al servidor. Aquí os dejo el programa tal y como está ahora mismo:

Servidor...

```
#pragma comment (lib, "ws2_32.lib")
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <iostream>


using namespace cv;
#pragma warning(disable: 4996)

#define FRAME_WIDTH         640
#define FRAME_HEIGHT        480

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int n, imgSize, bytes = 0, IM_HEIGHT, IM_WIDTH;
    Mat img;

    //WSAStartup inicia la libreria
    WSAData wsaData;
    WORD DLLVersion = MAKEWORD(2, 1);
    if (WSAStartup(DLLVersion, &wsaData) != 0) {
        std::cout << "Error\n";
        exit(1);
    }

    SOCKADDR_IN addr;
    int sizeofaddr = sizeof(addr);
    addr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    addr.sin_port = htons(56700);
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;

    SOCKET sListen = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL);
    bind(sListen, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, sizeof(addr));
    listen(sListen, SOMAXCONN);

    SOCKET newConnection;
    newConnection = accept(sListen, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, &sizeofaddr);

    if (newConnection == 0) {
        std::cout << "Error #2\n";
    }
    else {
        Mat img;
        img = Mat::zeros(480, 640, CV_8UC1);
        int imgSize = img.total() * img.elemSize();
        uchar* iptr = img.data;
        int bytes = 0;
        int key = 0;

        //make img continuos
        if (!img.isContinuous()) {
            img = img.clone();
        }

        std::cout << "Image Size:" << imgSize << std::endl;


        namedWindow("CV Video Client", 1);

        while (key != 'q') {

            char* dp = reinterpret_cast<char*>(iptr);
            if ((bytes = recv(newConnection, dp, imgSize, MSG_WAITALL)) == -1) {
                std::cerr << "recv failed, received bytes = " << bytes << std::endl;
            }

            cv::imshow("CV Video Client", img);

            if (key = cv::waitKey(10) >= 0) break;
        }

    }
}
```

Cliente...

```
#pragma comment (lib, "ws2_32.lib")
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <iostream>


using namespace cv;
#pragma warning(disable: 4996)


#define FRAME_WIDTH         640
#define FRAME_HEIGHT        480

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    int n, imgSize, IM_HEIGHT, IM_WIDTH;
    char buffer[256];
    VideoCapture cap(0);
    Mat cameraFeed;

    WSAData wsaData;
    WORD DLLVersion = MAKEWORD(2, 1);
    if (WSAStartup(DLLVersion, &wsaData) != 0) {
        std::cout << "Error #1\n";
        exit(1);
    }

    SOCKADDR_IN addr;
    int sizeofaddr = sizeof(addr);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("IP");
    addr.sin_port = htons(56700);
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;

    SOCKET Connection = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL);
    if (connect(Connection, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) != 0) {
        std::cout << "Error #2\n";
    }
    else {
        Mat img, imgGray;
        img = Mat::zeros(480, 640, CV_8UC1);
        //make it continuous
        if (!img.isContinuous()) {
            img = img.clone();
        }

        int imgSize = img.total() * img.elemSize();
        int bytes = 0;
        int key;


        //make img continuos
        if (!img.isContinuous()) {
            img = img.clone();
            imgGray = img.clone();
        }

        std::cout << "Image Size:" << imgSize << std::endl;

        while (1) {

            /* get a frame from camera */
            cap >> img;

            //do video processing here 
            cvtColor(img, imgGray, CV_16FC1);

            //send processed image
            const char* dp = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(imgGray.data);
            if ((bytes = send(Connection, dp, imgSize, 0)) < 0) {
                std::cerr << "bytes = " << bytes << std::endl;
                break;
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Antes funcionaba, solo que se veía en blanco y negro. Intenté cambiar la línea en la que pone `cvtColor(img, imgGray, CV_16FC1);`, ya que es la que se encarga del color del vídeo, pero entonces al ejecutarlo salen todas las pestañas incluida la de la webcam, pero  solo salía un cuadro gris y si trataba de interactuar con la página ponía que no responde. Además, el programa de cliente se cerraba automáticamente a los 20 segundos, sin excepción. He intentado volver a ponerlo como estaba antes en blanco y negro. No obstante, sigue dando el mismo error y no sé que hacer.

Comment: El problema que tienes aquí es que no solo has tocado esa línea. Has modificado algo más y no recuerdas qué. Mi consejo es que te acostumbres a usar repositorios de software y a hacer commits frecuentes. Por lo demás, me temo que te toca enfundarte un buen par de guantes y ponerte a depurar. Mira a ver qué parte es la que falla (cliente o servidor), ve aislando el fallo hasta que des con el origen te tus dolores de cabeza

Comment: Gracias eferion, intentaré solucionarlo.